# mongoose to determine update-upsert is doing insert or update

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to test if "upsert" option for updating is woking fine. So I "upsert" an object into mongodb  twice with same key. However it didn't show inserted message. Was I missing something ?

(mongodb : v2.6.3; mongoose : 3.8.15)

```
Member.findOneAndRemove({user_id: 1},
    function (err, doc) {
        if (!err) onsole.log(doc ? 'deleted' : 'not found');
}); // -> deleted, make sure user_id = 1 doesn't exist

Member.update({user_id: 1}, 
    {$set: {name: "name1"}}, 
    {upsert: true, new: false}, // new : false, so that I can detect original doc is null then know it's a new one.
    function (err, doc) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(doc ? 'updated' : 'inserted')
    }
}); // -> updated ? But it shoule be inserted, right ?

Member.update({user_id: 1}, 
    {$set: {name: "name2"}}, 
    {upsert: true, new: false},
    function (err, doc) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(doc ? 'updated' : 'inserted')
    }
}); // -> updated, yes, no problem.
```

Thank you for any hint.

============ answer =============

Use [.findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) instead of .update !
Moreover, make sure option is {upsert: true, **new: false**}, 
so that the callback's 2nd parameter(doc) could be original document in case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`.update()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) method in mongoose takes three arguments to the callback, being `err`, the `numAffected`, and a `raw` response. Use the "raw" object to see what happened:

```
Member.update({user_id : 1}, 
    {$set : {name:"name1"}}, 
    {upsert : true }, 
    function (err, numAffected, raw) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(raw)
    }
});
```

You'll see a structure like this:

```
{ ok: true,
  n: 1,
  updatedExisting: false,
  upserted: [ { index: 0, _id: 5456fc7738209001a6b5e1be } ] }
```

So there is always the `n` and 'updatedExisting`keys available, where the second is false on upserts and true otherwise.`upserted`will contain the`_id` values of any new documents created.

As for `n` or the "numAffected", this is basically always 1 where a document was matched under the legacy write concern responses.

You can see the new WriteResult response in MongoDB 2.6 and above using the Bulk Operations form:

```
var bulk = Member.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
bulk.find({user_id : 1}.upsert().update({$set : {name:"name1"}});
bulk.execute(err,result) {
   console.log( JSON.stringify( result, undefined, 2 ) );
}
```

Which on a first iteration you get something like this:

```
{
  "ok": 1,
  "writeErrors": [],
  "writeConcernErrors": [],
  "nInserted": 0,
  "nUpserted": 1,
  "nMatched": 0,
  "nModified": 0,
  "nRemoved": 0,
  "upserted": [
    {
      "index": 0,
      "_id": "5456fff138209001a6b5e1c0"
    }
  ]
}
```

And a second with the same parameters like this:

```
{
  "ok": 1,
  "writeErrors": [],
  "writeConcernErrors": [],
  "nInserted": 0,
  "nUpserted": 0,
  "nMatched": 1,
  "nModified": 0,
  "nRemoved": 0,
  "upserted": []
}
```

And the document would only be marked as "modified" where something was actually changed.

So at any rate, `.update()` operations do not return the modified document or the original document. That is the `.findOneAndUpdate()` method, a mongoose wrapper around the basic `.findAndModify()` which performs an atomic operation. The `.update()` methods are typically meant for bulk operations and as such do not return document content.

Comment: I just finish test .findOneAndUpdate and yes, it showed what I want and what you mentioned. Still I can use .update() to accomplish the same goal. But .findOneAndUpdate is the best and simple way in this case. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Kevin `.findOneAndUpdate()` does not actually tell you if something is "upserted" or not. Especially with a "new" option set (which is the default for mongoose). You could only tell by `"new": false`, and work backwards from there.

Comment: I should have said use .findOneAndUpdate() with option {upsert: ture, new: false}. Just a .findOneAndUpdate() call will still make the answer confusing. Thanks for reminding !

Comment: @NeilLunn Can you explain what you mean by "work backwards from there"? As far as I can tell, setting "new": false doesn't tell if the record was inserted or updated.. Actually, do you mean you look for "_id" field in the old document, and if it exists, assume that the record was updated?

Answer (score 7):

Regarding the OPs edit of the original question to use `.findOneAndUpdate`, you can also now pass the `rawResult: true` parameter, which return the document along with the data you would normally get from running `.update`, i.e.:

```
{ 
  updatedExisting: true,
  n: 1,
  ok: 1
}
```

Which should be sufficient to answer the original question of knowing whether you inserted or upserted.

I find this set of options to be generally desirable for upserts using `.findOneAndUpdate`:

```
  {
    upsert: true,
    new: true,
    runValidators: true,
    setDefaultsOnInsert: true,
    rawResult: true,
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

May add [timestamp](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/timestamps.html) to your schema, set the `new` option to `true` to get the updated or created document back and then compare `createdAt` & `updatedAt` values.

```
const memberSchema = new Schema({ user_id: String, age: Number }, {
  timestamps: true,
})

const Member = model('member', memberSchema)

const filter = { user_id: 'abcdef' }
const update = { age: 20 }

const document = await Member.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, {
  new: true,
  upsert: true,
})

const isInserted = document.createdAt.toISOString() === document.updatedAt.toISOString()
```