# mongoose findOneAndUpdate check if collection actually updated

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this code

```
export const edit = (req, res) => {
    Model.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body.id}, req.body, { new: true })
    .then((invoice) => {
        if(!invoice) {
            return res.status(404).send('model not found');
        }

        res.json({
            success: true,
            message: 'model updated successfully'
        });
    })
    .catch(err => res.send(err));
}
```

and when I pass right id it always returns

> model updated successfully

How can I check if a collection actually updated?

If I pass some argument for example `name` with new value it updates correctly but when I pass old value in `name` it anyway says that it's updated

Comment: Do you want to see the updated Collection database or something else ..?

Comment: nope. I just want to check if collection actually updated and that body wasn't with old values

Comment: You can use **returnNewDocument : true** ,which would return the updated document instead of  **new: true**.

Comment: Pretty sure [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26708684/8574934) answer can help you. Read raw.modifiedCount.