# mongodb updateOne() - determine upsert, insert or update occurred

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

After struggling with:
[mongoose to determine update-upsert is doing insert or update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26708036/mongoose-to-determine-update-upsert-is-doing-insert-or-update)

I'm still at a loss for determining whether and update or insert occurred with something like this:

```
        let updateResult = await myDB.updateOne(
            searchKey,
            newData,
            { upsert: true }
        );
```

updateResult contains:

```
{ n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1 }
```

nModified does not seem to indicate whether the operation resulted in an update or insert but rather it seems to have some other undertermined meaning.

```
$ mongod --version
db version v4.4.18
Build Info: {
    "version": "4.4.18",
    "gitVersion": "8ed32b5c2c68ebe7f8ae2ebe8d23f36037a17dea",
    "openSSLVersion": "OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "tcmalloc",
    "environment": {
        "distmod": "ubuntu2004",
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}

"mongoose": "^5.10.13",
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using mongoose then you will get below result when update

```
{
    "acknowledged": true,
    "modifiedCount": 1,        // if document is updated 
    "upsertedId": null,        // id of new inserted document (if upsert) 
    "upsertedCount": 0,        // count of inserted documents
    "matchedCount": 1          // count of documents that match with condition for update
}
```

Comment: how do I get this?